# Create React App command does not make react components

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My question is pretty easy but could not find what is the error.
I try to create new project on React but when I try, I can see only packetJson files but components are not created.

[image]

I have no error while installing as well.
How can I fix it?

Comment: It might help if you share the exact command you used

Comment: Like normal command that : npx create-react-app cloudhw

Comment: Try clearing npx cache using this command `npx clear-npx-cache` and then recreate the app

Comment: Did that but not helped

Comment: can you check your node version?

Comment: npm: '8.5.5',
 node: '16.15.0',